# How to stop large float numbers from being output in exponential form. (scientific notation?)

Tags: c++

I have a program that calculates population growth. It seems to be working but after when the population exceed 1 million it is output as a decimal number raised to a power of ten. (is this called scientic notation? exponential form? i forget.)

Is there anyway to output the data as a full number? Here is the code for the output where I will have to convert it.

```
#include "header.h"

void output (float currentPopulation, float years, float birthRate, float deathRate)

{     
     cout <<  "the populaion in " << years << " years will be: " << estimatedPopulation (currentPopulation, years, birthRate, deathRate) << endl;
}
```

New code:

```
#include "header.h"

    void output (float currentPopulation, float years, float birthRate, float deathRate)

    {     
         cout <<  "the populaion in " << years << " years will be: " << fixed << setprecision(0) << estimatedPopulation (currentPopulation, years, birthRate, deathRate) << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`std::fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/) manipulator, used in conjunction with [`std::setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/) should help you (remember to `#include <iomanip>`).

Answer (score 1):

With float you only have 24 bits of precision which is about 16,777,216. If you are dealing with numbers greater than that and you need more precision consider using `double` though I think you will still have to do some formatting to get it to looks the way you want. In which case I recommend you look at http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html and http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/io/omanipulators.html.

```
cout << fixed << estimatedPopulation (currentPopulation, years, birthRate, deathRate)
```

Comment: It only adds an exponent when the number exceeds 1 million. would it not do the same with double?

Comment: Updated my answer a bit but I think you need to set *fixed* as per my (new) second link.

Comment: float vs. double is irrelevant to the output format.  The default will switch to exponential notation for both when they get sufficiently large.

Comment: Well, populations rarely fit into the *millions* anymore so yeah, it could. I have updated my answer to included using *fixed*.

Comment: Excellent, only problem is that it outputs with 6 zeros after the decimal point but if i use static_cast<int> it displays the desired results :) thanks

Comment: The 0s are defined by setprecision, so setprecision(0) should take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest reading about `std::scientific`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szb722da(VS.71).aspx

Comment: This is the closest to an answer to the question that was asked, but I think the OP is really looking for [std::fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z328y9b3%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
float v(1234567891000000.0f);
cout.precision(0);
cout << fixed << v << endl;
```

Note loss of accuracy inherent in float: output is

> 1234567948140544

Answer (score 0):

Use printf instead, like `printf("%f", myvalue)`.

Comment: I personally find printf, and C stdio generally, a lot easier to remember how to use than C++ iostreams.  YMMV.

Comment: Indeed, why not? Of all the things in the standard C library, printf() is probably the best one.

Comment: For a good example of why not to use C stdio in C++, try writing a printf statement that prints out a `size_t` variable in code that's meant to be cross-platform (or compile on g++ and VS).